# Why do I get the message "user does not exist" after successful registration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a simple login and registration page. When I enter all the fields in the registration page, it responds with a "user registered successfully" yet when I log in to that user I get "user does not exist". Again, when I register with the same credentials, I get "user already exists"? What could be wrong here? Here's my auth controller:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");

module.exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const newUser = new User({ username: username, email: email, password: password });
    const saltRounds = 10;
    User.findOne({ email })
        .then(user => {
            if (password) {
                if (user) {
                    res.status(400).send("User already exists.", user);
                } else {
                    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (err, salt) {
                        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            newUser.password = hash;
                            newUser.save()
                                .then(user => {
                                    jwt.sign(
                                        { id: user._id },
                                        config.get('jwtsecret'),
                                        { expiresIn: 3600 },
                                        (err, token) => {
                                            if (err) throw err;
                                            console.log({
                                                token,
                                                user: {
                                                    id: user._id,
                                                    username: user.username,
                                                    email: user.email
                                                }
                                            });
                                            res.send("User registered.")
                                        }
                                    )
                                })
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        })
}

module.exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist" });
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                .then(matched => {
                    if (!matched) res.status(400).json(({ msg: "Invalid credentials" }))
                    jwt.sign(
                        { id: user._id },
                        config.get('jwtsecret'),
                        { expiresIn: 3600 },
                        (err, token) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.send({
                                token,
                                user: {
                                    id: user._id,
                                    name: user.name,
                                    email: user.email
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    )
                })
        })
}
```

Here's my login post request:

```
setUser({ email: form.email.value, password: form.password.value });
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/login", user)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("An error occured: ", err.response);
        })
```

And my register post request:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/register", user)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setRegistered(true);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("An error occured: ", err.response.data);
    })
```

Also, when I click on the register button it doesn't show anything. I have to click twice to get the response. Why does that happen?

Comment: Have you tried logging the email in the backed from the the Login function. To see if it's actually being sent? Also, using async/await will make it a lot easier to follow and read IMO.

Comment: Yes, I have. It's not being sent. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try using async await then.

Comment: It is being sent now, I fixed that, but again it's the same problem

Comment: Assuming you are executing these requests in order ( i.e wait until register resolves before sending login ) it seems it's a validator issue - for example if your email has a trailing space "email@google.com " will not match "email@google.com". before you take this at face value i am not specifically saying a trailing space is the specific issue. i would start by printing both emails in both routes to make sure they are identical.

Comment: I figured it out! I'm still not sure exactly what went wrong, but it seems that not using a state variable for sending requests helped. Thanks a lot anyway!